# Stored procedure inside cursor not updating local variable from output parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, cursors

I'm having trouble with the output parameter of a stored procedure that's being executed inside the while loop of a cursor.

```
DECLARE @p_in int
DECLARE @p_out char

OPEN crs_clientId

FETCH NEXT FROM crs_clientId INTO @p_in

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @p_in

    EXEC dbo.usp_get_letter_for_number
             @in = @p_in, @out = @p_out OUTPUT;

    PRINT @p_out

    FETCH NEXT FROM crs_clientId INTO @p_in
END

CLOSE crs_clientId
DEALLOCATE crs_clientId
```

If I run this stored procedure independently, I get:

```
1
A
2
B
3
C
```

However, running it within the the cursor I get:

```
1
A
2
A
3
A
```

What am I missing? Why is the stored procedure only updating `@p_out` on the first pass?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo.  The end of the loop is  
     FETCH NEXT FROM crs_clientId INTO @p_in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not sure what exactly the problem was, but the fix was to set the @p_out to null at the beginning of each pass of the cursor.  For some reason, if the @p_out wasn't null, the output of the stored procedure wouldn't write to it.

The loop now looks like this and works correctly:

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @p_in
    SET @p_out = NULL;

    EXEC dbo.usp_get_letter_for_number
         @in = @p_in, @out = @p_out output

    PRINT @p_out

    FETCH NEXT FROM crs_clientId INTO @p_in
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how are you getting 1,2,3,4 in output. As code seems to have issue.

You are assigning a value to cursor in the end which seems incorrect variable

See `@c_clientId` in `FETCH NEXT`

So maybe your have posted half code.

Or you need to assign value to correct varable i.e. `@p_in` in end of cursor loop to get correct value

I tried to simulate with a sample procedure to return values

```
--sample stored procedure
create procedure usp_get_letter_for_number(@in int, @out char(1) OUTPUT)
as
begin
    if @in = 1
        set @out = 'A'
    else if @in = 2
        set @out = 'B'
    else if @in = 3
        set @out =  'C'
    else 
        set @out = 'Z'
end
```

And used your code and corrected it to use `@pin` instead of `@c_clientId` with sample SELECT statement

```
DECLARE @p_in int
DECLARE @p_out char
DECLARE crs_clientId CURSOR FOR SELECT top 10 id from Users /*Sample sql query*/
OPEN crs_clientId

FETCH NEXT FROM crs_clientId INTO @p_in

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @p_in

    EXEC dbo.usp_get_letter_for_number
             @in = @p_in, @out = @p_out output

    PRINT @p_out

    FETCH NEXT FROM crs_clientId INTO @p_in
END

CLOSE crs_clientId
DEALLOCATE crs_clientId
```

Output

```
1
A
2
B
3
C
4
Z
5
Z
:
:
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.  I've fixed it.